# returning a string from a function in c with parameters 4

Tags: c, function, pointers, c-strings

Please look the code below

```
#include<stdio.h>
char* day(int);
int main()
{ 
   int num;
   char *p;
   printf("Enter the day \n");
   scanf("%d",&num);
   p=day(num);
   printf("%s",*p);
   return 0;
}

char *day(int num)
{
   char *str;
   switch(num)
   {
   case 1: *str="MONDAY";
           break;
   case 2: *str="TUESDAY";
           break;
   case 3: *str="WEDNESDAY";
           break;
   case 4: *str="THURSDAY";
           break;
   case 5: *str="FRIDAY";
           break;
   case 6: *str="SATURDAY";
           break;
   case 7: *str="SUNDAY";
          break;
   }
   return str;
}
```

I'm trying to print the days in a week in the above program in order to achieve this I have created a function day() which will accept the number from the user and will return the address of day but the above program is not working .I don't know what is the problem.Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Remove  **'*'** from str in day function, as you are assigning contents through pointers

Go through [Basic Pointer Operations](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10a.html) for pointer fundamentals.

```
 #include<stdio.h>


  char* day(int);
  int main()
 { 
   int num;
   char *p;
  printf("Enter the day \n");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  p=day(5);
  printf("%s",p);
   return 0;
 }

  char* day(int num)
 {
  char* str;
   switch(num)
 {
   case 1: str="MONDAY";
           break;
   case 2: str="TUESDAY";
           break;
   case 3: str="WEDNESDAY";
           break;
   case 4: str="THURSDAY";
           break;
   case 5: str="FRIDAY";
           break;
   case 6: str="SATURDAY";
           break;
   case 7: str="SUNDAY";
          break;
   }

    return str;
 }
```

I hope it does make sense to you....

Comment: why we are not using *p as we have to access the value pointed by pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `printf("%s" p)` without the '*'.

*p means the value at the address that is stored in p. p is a char pointer, so if you used that, you would only be passing a single char to `printf`.

If you don't use the '*' you are passing the address in memory that to string starts at. This lets `printf` print that first char, then the second, then third and so on until it reaches the end of the string (a null character, '\0').
Also, when you are assigning the string to the char pointer, you don't want to use '*' there either. See Maharajs answer for working code.